# jQuery scroll to content when clicked

Tags: jquery

```
$('.jumbotron').click(function(event){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: window.pageYOffset + $(window).height() }, 500);
});
```

How can I change the + mark to a minus? It immediately breaks if I change the order... So jumbotron is 100vh just need to scroll 100vh or the remaining if scrolled.

Comment: Find the offset of the element `.jumbotron` and scroll to this position instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery scroll to element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Answer (score 1):

Am I correct in interpreting that you want to vertically scroll have `.jumbotron` at the top of the window?

Try setting `scrollTop` to `$(this).offset().top`.

https://api.jquery.com/offset/